# "Circular view path" with simple spring-boot app using @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple spring-boot application that serves up static content.  I have an index.html page and some js/css in /src/main/resources/public.  I have a single simple controller as follows:

```
@Controller
public class PublicController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

That works as expected.  I run `curl http://localhost:8080/`, and it delivers my html.

Now I want to modify the controller to take a path variable:

```
// ...
@RequestMapping(value="/{word}", method=RequestMapping.GET)
public String index(@PathVariable("word") String word) {
    return "index";
}
```

But now I get a 500 with a big long "Circular view path" exception.

I presume what's happening is the view resolver is seeing that my controller can handle "/index", and realises that's not going to end well.

Is it possible to tell the view resolver to give the static resources priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Thymeleaf` and declare declare a `ThymeleafViewResolver` and a `ServletContextTemplateResolver` with a specific prefix and suffix, it builds the `View` differently, giving it a path like

```
WEB-INF/static/index.html
```

`ThymeleafView` instances locate the file relative to the `ServletContext` path by using a `ServletContextResourceResolver`

```
templateInputStream = resourceResolver.getResourceAsStream(templateProcessingParameters, resourceName);
```

which eventually

```
return servletContext.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```

This gets a resource that is relative to the `ServletContext` path. It can then use the `TemplateEngine` to generate the HTML. There's no way an endless loop can happen here.

Comment: Changing to Thymeleaf fixed my problem.  Thanks!